# "POST /test.php" Error (404): "Not found"

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

***Warning: I'm a total newbie to php.***

I followed a tutorial for writing a php script that takes input from a sign-up page (html) and stores it in a database (mysql/Wamp). But when I tried to test it to see if everything's working, I get this:

```
"GET /tester.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36"
"POST /test.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36"
"POST /test.php" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I don't understand why it can't find test.php. I have it referenced in the html, as you can see:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register Form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="/test.php" method="POST">   <--- php reference
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Name :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Password :</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

A straight up solution would be great, but ways to find out what I need to google would also work.

EDIT1:

Here's my file structure. It's very simple.

[image: File structure]

Comment: do you have a file called test.php?

Comment: did you try it without slash here ->>> `/test.php`

Comment: Are you running a local PHP server? (e.g. WAMP). Browsers will load any HTML file by default but that doesn't mean you have a web server running. If you're accessing the file directly (i.e. loading that file path into the address bar) - you probably don't have a server running or your accessing it incorrectly. Most web servers host by default on `localhost`

Comment: So your URL (when accessing tester.html) should probably be like `http://localhost/tester.html` or similar. The form should then POST to `http://localhost/test.php`

Comment: @SohanArafat Yes, I did. That was how I originally had it and got this same error. I gave it a slash since that's what it had in the error.

Comment: @Rylee I'm running localhost with node.js

Comment: @Rylee That's what it tries to do, but it fails. It gives me "http://127.0.0.1:8080/tester.html" and then "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.php" but tells me that the page isn't working while throwing the error I showed above.

Comment: Are you using a Node server and attempting to run a PHP file? That's not how it works - Node will load `.js` files only. You need to run a web server for PHP if that's the case. Most common one is apache.

Comment: Yeah, that would explain it.

Answer (score 1):

the '/' in your `action` will set the path back to root, so if your form and php are in a directory `http://eaxmple.com/this/is/a/path/tester.html` your form action will return to `http://eaxmple.com/test.php`

if you want them in the same directory change `action='test.php'` or to the path that the file resides :)

but without seeing your file structure I'm not 100%

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register Form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="test.php" method="POST">   <--- php reference
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Name :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Password :</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error though. Completely unchanged.

Comment: @GrantAllan could you take a screenshot of your folder structure; where the files are relative to your root

Comment: I added it in. It's pretty simple though. One html, one php, both in the same folder called "test"

Answer (score 1):

remove '/'
`<form action="/test.php" method="POST"> ---> <form action="test.php" method="POST">`

maybe can help you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have run it on a server not locally .
Try to configure your apache server locally if you are not working on a server because php scripts runs only on a server environment.

Comment: thats not true, I have PHP in my windows env running in client mode

Comment: where is test.php placed ? i mean it's path , try to put it under www folder

Comment: @CharfeddineMohamedAli I'm running an http-server to localhost it. Is that wrong? It's what people were saying to do when I googled it.

Comment: it's not wrong , Can we have a look where your test.php is ? also did you try to put it under /www/ folder?

Comment: the problem is where you are placing the test.php folder , if it is under /www/ your code should work , if it the path /www/project/(index.html and test.php) try to action="/project/test.php"